# Microsoft.SqlServer.Types (14.0) To Access its Geographical Capabitlies

Tags: sql-server

We have an MVC Core (3) application that uses the **Microsoft.SqlServer.Types (14.0)** library.
However, this library is mainly designed for .NET 4 and not core. Is there an equivalent library we can use in an MVC Core (3) application?

Many Thanks.

Comment: [Spatial support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial) was added in EF Core 2.2. and later through the NetTopologySuite packages

Comment: WHoever voted to close probably didn't understand the question. This isn't a question asking for a library recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spatial support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial) was added in EF Core 2.2. and later through the NetTopologySuite packages for PostgreSQL, SQL Server, SQLite.

This allows you to use spatial property types and have EF Core map them to SQL Server types, eg :

```
class Country
{
    public int CountryID { get; set; }

    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    // Database includes both Polygon and MultiPolygon values
    public Geometry Border { get; set; }
}
```

EF Core can also use spatial functions in queries :

```
var nearestCity = db.Cities
    .OrderBy(c => c.Location.Distance(currentLocation))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

For raw ADO.NET queries, you can use [NetTopologySuite.IO.SqlServerBytes](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite.IO.SqlServerBytes) directly, eg:

```
var geometryReader = new SqlServerBytesReader { IsGeography = true };
var bytes = dataReader.GetSqlBytes(columnOrdinal).Value;
var geometry = geometryReader.Read(bytes);
```

Or

```
var geometry = new Point(-122.129797, 47.640049) { SRID = 4326 };
var geometryWriter = new SqlServerBytesWriter { IsGeography = true };
var bytes = geometryWriter.Write(geometry);
var parameter = command.Parameters
    .AddWithValue(parameterName, new SqlBytes(bytes));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How would one do something like : var dist = geog.STDistance(SqlGeography.STPointFromText(new SqlChars("POINT(" + d.Longitude + " " + d.Latitude + ")"), 4326)).Value;

Comment: Sorry. Thanks for mentioning it was included in Core 2.2 That sorted my issue. Cheers

Comment: We are using the std formula but we keep getting Zero back as the distance. Is there any where we are supposed to specify the srid?  
var geo = new GeometryFactory();

var point1 = geo.CreatePoint(new Coordinate(double.Parse(lng, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), double.Parse(lat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

var point2 = geo.CreatePoint(new Coordinate(double.Parse(d.Longitude, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), double.Parse(d.Latitude, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

var dist = point1.Distance(point2);

Comment: @user2981411 that's a [NetTopologySuite](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite) question, not a SQL Server or EF Core question. NTS is an OSS that has In any case, the SRID is specified when you create the geometries, not when you try to perform calculations with them. Use one of the [NtsGeometryServices.CreateGeometryFactory](http://nettopologysuite.github.io/NetTopologySuite/api/NetTopologySuite.NtsGeometryServices.html#NetTopologySuite_NtsGeometryServices_CreateGeometryFactory_System_Int32_) methods that accept an SRID